# Updating Firestore if field exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple app that allows a user to input an email address and a date.

I have a collection within Firestore with document names auto-generated and the two fields saved there. Like this:
[image]

I want to be able to update only the date if the email id is already in the database (not much help if it updates the email address for a matching date as there will be many duplicate dates).

Any help would be fantastic.

Here is my JS so far:

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

const docRef = btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    e.preventDefault,
    setDoc(doc(db, "candidates", mail), {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        date: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(document.getElementById("date").value)),
    });
});
```

Issue solved, final working code:

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");


const docRef = btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    e.preventDefault,
    setDoc(doc(db, "candidates", mail), {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        date: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(document.getElementById("date").value)),

    
    });
});

const candidateRef = doc(db, "candidates", mail);

await updateDoc(candidateRef, {
  date: date
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to update only the date if the email id is already
> in the database

You should first query the database to check if a document with the email exists and if it does you update the doc.

Something along the following lines (we make the assumption that there is only one document per email):

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "candidates"), where("email", "==", "..."));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
if (querySnapshot.size === 1) {
   const docRef = querySnapshot.docs[0].ref;
   await updateDoc(docRef, {...});
}
```

---

Note that you may use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) depending on your functional requirements and data model.
In this case you'll need to use the email as the document ID because you cannot use a Query in a Transaction with the JS SDK.

Comment: Thanks for this. In trying your code I get an unexpected token on {...} where you use the updateDoc method. Any idea why?

Comment: Also I just changed the document title to the email address and moved to the setDoc command. Just to tidy things up a little but not sure that'll have any bearing on your response.

Comment: I got it working, thank you! I just had to declare the variables outside of my onclick function and then run the if statement inside the onclick function. I'll put the working code in my question.

Comment: Code doesn't seem to be working any more. How strange.

Comment: Got it working, used the updateDoc method. That was a long slog!